# JavaFX interactivity with Spring MVC Restful

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, javafx-8, interactive

I am building a JavaFX client application communicating with Spring MVC Restful server(Spring boot 1.4.1) application which works as expected.

Some features require fast interaction with the server to validate limits and availability before proceeding to next input example check if member number insert is valid and if has exceeded  limit to insert, during accumulation of records(each confirmed record temporarily stored in a tableview before sent to server for storage) before the records are actually saved.

Within JavaFX and Spring framework(in both frontend and backend) scope, how can such kind of features made look more interactive(or live) than normal "let-me-wait-for-response" approach

If question is not clear, just ask, otherwise i think it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the only interaction you have between client (JavaFX) and server (SpringBoot) is through a REST API. This will make short bursts of data (such a validation) take longer.

Switching to another communication mechanism (for example gRPC or Netty with Msgpack) could help. Note that once you open the door for non-REST calls it'll make you re-think the use of REST in the first place.

Non-REST communication may not be an option depending on your requirements (firewalls, etc) or may need additional setup in order to surmount other obstacles, in other words, there's no free lunch.

Comment: is there a difference between gRPC and websocket which has been integrated with spring 4?

Comment: Yes, there are two different beasts. Websockets enables server-side push on top of HTTP/1.1. gRPC enables HTTP/2.0 and data streaming from both sides, even simultaneously.

Comment: is it possible to use both REST and gRPC in the same app?

Comment: Yes, but you won't be able to reuse the same communication channels. You must write a communication interface for each option

Comment: Could you please provide grpc client maven dependancies? I posted a question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188914/javafx-grpc-client-dependencies">here</a>